# How to drive TM1668 7 segment Control via STM32?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, led-driver, software

There is a curcuit diagram which is in the below. My aim is basically able to write these segments some numbers. For example, in Grid 2 side able to write 6, Grid 3 side able to write 7 etc. But my aim is not use a specific library, how can ı do that which is the easiest way with stm32.
Should ı use SPI or another. Can you help me with the code.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://www.artschip.com/pdf/HT1668.PDF).